# Prevent nullification on update using Rails validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a rails 5 API that has the following validations:

```
validates :key, presence: true, on: :create
validates :key, uniqueness: true
validates :name, presence: true, on: :create
validates :type, presence: true, on: :create
```

`on: create` is used to make sure that the validations do not prevent updates. I would like to add an additional validation to ensure that any of these fields are not made null at any point, like on update or otherwise.

I assume I'll use `allow_nil: false` somewhere, but I'm not sure where to put it, because I want to make sure that null values are never allowed, not just on create.

Comment: Why would you not just remove the `on: :create`?

Comment: What evidence do you have that your validations prevent updates?